# Hide label in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm building a Crystal Report with Visual Studio 2015.
So I have a section like this:

[image]

Now, I can have section without parameter and If I try to start my report I have this situation:

[image]

Now I want change my report and if I don't have parameter for this section the Crystal Report not must to show this label "*Parametro, Valore, U.m: Valori Riferimento*" and line.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new formula (e.g. `countElement`) with the following content:

```
Count ({table_name.column_name})
```

You can use this formula to suppress the header / header items. You have to enable the the `suppress` option on the properties of the header / header items and set the following formula:

```
{?countElement} < 1
```

---

To set the `suppress` option you have to right click on the item which you want to suppress (with condition) and choose `Format Object`. There you choose the `Common` tab and enable the option `Suppress`. On the right side you can open the Formula Workshop of the `Suppress` option. There you have to insert the condition (`{?countElement} < 1`) to hide the item.

- [Suppress field in Crystal Reports](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/497072/Suppress-field-in-Crystal-Reports)

Comment: Ok, I have created under Formula Fields a new formula (countElement). Now I have insert your code with my table name and column name. But now I don't know how can I apply this formula of my labels

Comment: I added a explanation and a link to a explanation with images.

Comment: thanks you, if you can, you can explain also if the value of table_name.column_name is null or empty ?